# Creating a new dataframe from applying a function on all cell of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, df, like this:

```
data = {'A': ['Jason (121439)', 'Molly (194439)', 'Tina (114439)', 'Jake (127859)', 'Amy (122579)'], 
        'B': ['Bob (127439)', 'Mark (136489)', 'Tyler (121443)', 'John (126259)', 'Anna(174439)'], 
        'C': ['Jay (121596)', 'Ben (12589)', 'Toom (123586)', 'Josh (174859)', 'Al(121659)'],
        'D': ['Paul (123839)', 'Aaron (124159)', 'Steve (161899)', 'Vince (179839)', 'Ron (128379)']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I want to create a new data frame with one column with the name and the other column with the number between parenthesis, which would look like this:

```
data2 = {'Name': ['Jason ', 'Molly ', 'Tina ', 'Jake ', 'Amy '], 
        'ID#': ['121439', '194439', '114439', '127859', '122579']} 
result = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I try different things, but it all did not work:

1)

```
List_name=pd.DataFrame()
List_id=pd.DataFrame()
List_both=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","ID"])

for i in df.columns:
    left=df[i].str.split("(",1).str[0]
    right=df[i].str.split("(",1).str[1]
    List_name=List_name.append(left)
    List_id=List_id.append(right)

List_both=pd.concat([List_name,List_id], axis=1)
List_both
```

2) applying a function on all cell

```
Names = lambda x: x.str.split("(",1).str[0]
IDS = Names = lambda x: x.str.split("(",1).str[1]
```

But I was wondering how to do it in order to store it in a data frame that will look like `result`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` followed by `str.extract`.

```
(df.stack()
   .str.strip()
   .str.extract(r'(?P<Name>.*?)\s*\((?P<ID>.*?)\)$')
   .reset_index(drop=True))

     Name      ID
0   Jason  121439
1     Bob  127439
2     Jay  121596
3    Paul  123839
4   Molly  194439
5    Mark  136489
6     Ben   12589
7   Aaron  124159
8    Tina  114439
9   Tyler  121443
10   Toom  123586
11  Steve  161899
12   Jake  127859
13   John  126259
14   Josh  174859
15  Vince  179839
16    Amy  122579
17   Anna  174439
18     Al  121659
19    Ron  128379
```